# Superfish CSS: Make submenu dropdown vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

I have a superfish menu [here](https://composer.klnpa.org/) and I would like the submenu to dropdown vertically. I can achieve this by setting

```
.sf-menu.sf-style-white.sf-navbar li ul {
  width: 150px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

However, this is not a flexible solution because it will only work if I only have 1 parent-item that has a submenu and I would have to adjust it manually depending on where in the menu the link is. I'm looking for a way to dropdown submenu's below their parent items automatically.

Comment: It's difficult to work with a live site. Any chance you can post your code in a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below properties to your rules. This will help you.

```
.sf-menu.sf-style-white.sf-navbar li {
    position:relative;
}

.sf-menu.sf-style-white.sf-navbar li ul {
    left: 0;
}
```